# unable to find valid certification path to requested target with Quarkus

Tags: java, ssl, quarkus

I have secured my web app with Keycloak that is based on Quarkus. When I start the app:

```
./mvnw clean compile quarkus:dev
```

it shows me:

```
io.quarkus.oidc.OIDCException: OIDC server is not available at the 'quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url' URL. Please make sure it is correct. Note it has to end with a realm value if you work with Keycloak, for example: 'https://localhost:8180/auth/realms/quarkus'

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

The Keycloak server is setting up with certificate `https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory`(not a valid certificate), because it is a DEV environment.

The Keycloak configuration on Quarkus:

```
quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=https://dev.oic.databaker.io/auth/realms/databaker
quarkus.oidc.client-id=svc
quarkus.oidc.credentials.secret=!!!secret!!!
quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.enable=true
quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.paths.1.path=/
quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.paths.1.enforcement-mode=DISABLED
quarkus.ssl.native=false
```

How to bypass the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `acme-staging` Let's Encrypt certificates are for testing purposes and are **not** trusted by the CAs included with your system.

You need to add the [Fake LE Root X1](https://letsencrypt.org/certs/fakelerootx1.pem) root certificate to the list of trusted CA certificates.

This is detailed in the [Let's Encrypt Acme docs](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/staging-environment/#root-certificate):

> The staging environment intermediate certificate (“Fake LE
> Intermediate X1”) is issued by a root certificate not present in
> browser/client trust stores. If you wish to modify a test-only client
> to trust the staging environment for testing purposes you can do so by
> adding the “Fake LE Root X1” certificate to your testing trust store.
> Important: Do not add the staging root or intermediate to a trust
> store that you use for ordinary browsing or other activities, since
> they are not audited or held to the same standards as our production
> roots, and so are not safe to use for anything other than testing.

Comment: Keycloak server runs on Kubernetes and https://cert-manager.io/ is using to generate certificate. Where to I have to add `Fake LE Root X1`, on the app or Kubernetes?

Comment: The app needs to verify the Let's Encrypt certificate presented by Keyclock, so your app is the one that needs the CA certificate. Or better yet, use a real Let's Encrypt certificate, not one from the staging environment, that one is only for testing.

Comment: The Keycloak is running in the DEV environment. Should I anyway real certificate?

Comment: If your entire stack is in dev or staging, then staging Let's Encrypt is the right choice, you just need to add the CA where appropriate. Just make sure to use real Let's Encrypt certificates for production.